# Python: Struggling to mask part of a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this, I am reasonably new to Python and could do this in a minute in Matlab.

I am trying to Mask a certain latitude and longitude box for ocean data.

I can create the boolean mask maps for both the latitudes and longitudes. This gives me 101 Latitudes by 131 Longitudes (From the global dataset 181 x 361). But can't work out how to mask my 2d dataset in the same fashion so I can plot it on a pcolormesh plot.

Basically, my shapes are incorrect. 
How do I mask my dataset (same original shape as lat x lon) so the subset is the same shape as my lats/longs so the chosen area is plottable?

```
lat_mask=[(lat<=50)&(lat>=-50)]   #boolean for lat area
lat_masked=lat[lat_mask]          #the lat subset i want

lon_mask=[(lon>=-120)&(lon<=70)]
lon_masked=lon[lon_mask]

#Mask the Dataset - Error here. How I imagine it should work but does not 

data_masked=data[lat_mask,long_mask]  #this is how i would do it in matlab but not even close

#something like this works a bit better but is still not functional 
lam,lom= np.meshgrid(lat_mask,lon_mask)
data_masked = np.ma.array(data,mask=lom)

#plot
plt.pcolormesh(lom,lam,data)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is `data` a 2D `np.ndarray`? And what is ch1? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *data* is a numpy array then the following script should solve your problem

```
m, n = data.shape
data_masked = data[np.arange(m)[lat_mask][:, None], np.arange(n)[long_mask]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! There must be a few methods of doing this but works awesome.Thanks!!

Comment: @NicPittman always happy to help:-). Could you please mark my answer as a solution to your question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the mask directly to the **dataframe**, not to the column name:

```
masked_data = data[
   (data["lat_col_name"] <= 50) & 
   (data["lat_col_name"] >= -50) & 
   (data["lon_col_name"] >= -120) & 
   (data["lon_col_name"] <= 70)
]
```